WhatsApp template Status 'REJECTED' for header image
I am trying to create a WhatsApp template but it returning status REJECTED for the Header Image.
{
  name: templateName,
  category: "MARKETING",
  allow_category_change: true,
  language: "en",
  components: [{
      type: "HEADER",
      format: "IMAGE",
      example: {
        header_handle: [
          imgUrl
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      type: "BODY",
      text: description,
      example: {
        body_text: [bodyvariableName],
      },
    },
    {
      type: "BUTTONS",
      buttons: [{
        type: "URL",
        text: buttonFeild.buttonText,
        url: buttonFeild.websiteurl,
      }, ],
    },
  ],
};

However, when I created a template using a Text header then the template is creating successfully
{
  type: "HEADER",
  format: "TEXT",
  text: textareaValue,
  example: {
    header_text: [variableName],
  }
}

